# Show snackbar if no connection

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im using Netinfo from react-community and snackbar. I am trying to show the Snackbar when the user is not connected. The problem is the event is being fired but the snackbar is not showing. Code in App js.

```
import Snackbar from 'react-native-snackbar';
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
console.log("Connection type", state.type);
console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
Snackbar.show({
  text: 'No Internet Connection',
  duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT,
});
});
}

 render() {

 return (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Root>
      <AppNavigator ref={navigatorRef => { setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) 
   }}/>
    </Root>
  </Provider>
   );
  }
 }
```

Comment: Can you get Snackbar to display just by attaching it to a simple button? Trying to figure out if the problem is snackbar or netinfo... Also what else is in the render method? Does it still not work if it's just an empty screen?

Comment: yes the snackbar shows whenever I reload the screen.

Comment: And do the logs show when you go on and offline, or only when the component mounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd set the listener as a member outside the constructor so you can refer to it later when you want to unsubscribe. Try this...

```
export default class App extends Component {
  unsubscribeConnectionListener = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
    console.log('Connection type', state.type);
    console.log('Is connected?', state.isConnected);

    if (state.isConnected) return;

    Snackbar.show({
      text: 'No Internet Connection',
      duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
    });
  });

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeConnectionListener();
  }
}
```